# How do mathematicians estimate time needed to solve a problem?

Tags: education, math-history

This question relates to the nature of time-planning. I have not been able to find anything that would even come close to answering my question. Therefore, I want to find out, if there exists a methodology or are [my examples] just anecdotes, that do not lead anywhere.

I have two of them, one fictional, and one non-fictional:

1. In '*The Devotion of Suspect X*' by Higashino, there is a mathematician charachter called Ishigami. He mentions in the book, that he is working on a certain 'math problem', and that he calculated that coming up with a solution would take him 20 more years.
2. Marvin Minsky, an American computer scientist (now deceased) has mentioned in a keynote panel called 'The Golden Age', that he had a university friend in a maths department. This friend would work on a problem, that would supposedly take 9 years to be solved, '*but he finished it in 8*'. (I am sorry, but I was unable to come up with the mathematician's name).

I can understand time planning for buildings and computer systems, because you have to build something big. However working on something as abstract as math itself, where you have to 'figure something out', seems a totally different task to me.

Let's consider my 2 sources are strong enough to conclude that mathematicians are able to plan ahead for multiple years on a single problem. How do you approach this planning?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: My impression is that mathematicians are not able to predict with much accuracy when tough unsolved problems will be solved. As we venture further into the wilderness, we can predict that we will find new things, but we don’t know what those new things will be. Maybe we have seen glimpses of things that are out there and we can hope there will be no major obstacles in the way to reaching them.

Comment: Yeah, that is one of my main wonders... How do you take into the account all of the unknowns?

Comment: For things that simply need working through ('plug-and-chug') you can often get an idea about how long it'll take to complete. The path is more or less clear, you simply need to walk it though, perhaps, with machete. On the other hand, proving a conjecture typically won't be predictable at all simply because you often don't know if it's true. I suspect when someone says it'll take nine years to solve a problem, he or she typically means 'This one is going to take a while!'

Comment: To contrast with littleO’s comment (see a glimpse of a great thing, hope there’s no trouble on the road), there also are widely believed conjectures whose proof came as a total surprise, as they were expected to be beyond reach (an informal term, of course) with the current knowledge. With the same metaphor, it would be like seeing a treasure chest at the other end of a canyon and finding a bridge as you started to climb it down. Wiles’s proof of a large chunk of the Modularity Conjecture (completing the proof of Fermat’s Last Theorem) was one of them, for instance.

Comment: @littleO you say that 'as you venture into the wilderness, you can predict that you will find new things'. So you say, you can predict there will be something there, but, the time to reach it just ranges from 'not too much', to 'this'll take a while' (like 'A rural reader' mentioned/implied).

Comment: @Rok,  exactly what is the "specific situation" you mention? In other words, why do you care about this?

Comment: @WillJagy you asked a very good question. I have kind of butchered mine question, I shall edit it. I meant a situation where you are a mathematician, working on a big problem, like in the examples (and not like a student that is solving his homework assignments, for example). I am asking this, because I hope to get an insight, direction, maybe resources into the nature of such planning... or just another example, so I won't have only two.

Comment: This question seems to be based on a false premise about mathematicians' ability to plan, how mathematics research is done, or both. Beyond some immediate horizon (2-3 months?) *some* of the time, mathematicians don't pick an unsolved problem and say "I'm confident I'll be able to solve it in X time". Instead they *chip away* at problems/questions. I don't think anyone is scheduling years of work on a program with planned benchmarks or something.